# Connect Function

Tags: c++, qt, this, this-pointer

What is `this` in the following QT function call?

```
connect(findButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(findClicked()));
```

I know the background of `this` in C++ but what is `this` pointing to in this function call?

Comment: Pointer to instance of the class where you call the connect.

Comment: there is no `this` in C and no language called `C/C++` :).

Answer (score 2):

`this` points to the current object. The method is called from a member function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is more like a C++ question than Qt's one, If you dont know what it means, go and read some more about C++ rather than study Qt.
See this about [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In this example you are connecting:

- ***findButton***'s clicked() SIGNAL

with:

- ***this***'s findClicked() SLOT

***This*** is most likely the object in which the connect line's code is located.

To answer your question, you need to check and see what object is being created in the code that contains the connect call.